# How to run 2 fast-cgi (php-fpm) websites on an nginx server?

Tags: linux, nginx, php-fpm, virtualhost

I have nginx running with a few vhosts for different domains. One of them uses php-fpm. I need to add another vhost(for a new domain) that points to a new directory and that also has to use php-fpm. I have tried many different vhost configurations but no matter what I try, I can never get my new domain to point to the document root that I want it to. Every time the domain points to the particular website that uses php-fpm already. The domain has an A record with the server's IP. No redirections etc. I made sure that my links were properly made in the sites-enabled directory and I always reloaded nginx after fiddling with vhosts.
Can someone be so kind and post proper nginx vhost configurations to serve different php-fpm websites to different domains?

Edit:
Here are my current vhost configs(slightly simplified):

previous php-fpm website:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain1.com *.domain1.com;
    root /home/domain1/www;

    location / {
        index index.php;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {                                                                         
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 6000;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 6000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/domain1/www$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }
}
```

and the new website I'm trying to run:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain2.com *.domain2.com;
    root /home/domain2;

    location / {
        index index.php;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 6000;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 6000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/domain2$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please *edit* your post to include your configuration files. Please use the editing/formatting tools for this.

Comment: What are the real domains ? Did you make sure your `server_name` directive is correct regarding related DNS ?

Comment: @XavierLucas I won't post the real domains publicly, but yes - I am sure that the `server_name` directive is correct. Php-fpm is serving from the domain1 directory for both vhosts for some reason and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: Thanks for the tip :) I am happy to provide more information privately(skype/irc/whatever). I'm just out of ideas and would really appreciate some help.
edit: I will try moving `include` higher up right now.

Comment: @user277554 I believe it's due to your include directive after the definition of SCRIPT_FILENAME so it overrides the parameter. Move it up.

Comment: @XavierLucas I tried both moving it before the definition of `SCRIPT_FILENAME` and commenting it out completely. Still nothing.